# Why is this javascript/jquery image pre-loader not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).load(function() {

        // Preload images
        var images = [
                     'image0.png',
                 'image1.png',
                 'image2.png',
                 'image3.png'
              ],
              i,
              img;
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            img = new Image();
        img .src = images[i];
        }
});
```

I've tried `$(window).ready(function() { ...`

As well.

I can tell that it's not loading because when I switch images, I see the white flash (no image while loading image). What am I missing?

Comment: What is `img`? Did you forgot to initialize? Show HTML snippet too.

Comment: Is there any errors in debugger ? you've a space between `img` and `.src`

Comment: @Manwal , I don't know what img is for nor i, I thought they were for the for loop, but it's not a multi-variable declaration either.

Comment: @Alexis, there are no errors, the images are all present. The problem is the loading, I've tried at least three different methods from three different sources for pre-loading images with javascript/jquery.

Comment: @janicehoplin i've answer with a working example :-)

Comment: I saw it and thanks but, I don't think it's working on my end... I know that's not your problem, I'm going to try some more stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `$(window).load()` by `$(document).ready()`
and append your image or save them into an array in your loop.

Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Preload images
        var images = [
                  'image0.png',
                 'image1.png',
                 'image2.png',
                 'image3.png'
              ],
              i,
              img;
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            img.src = images[i];
            img.alt=images[i];
            $(".contain").append(img);
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain">


</div>
```

Comment: I think the changes that you specified worked, I just can't tell if they are actually working. I keep using incognito-windows to not cache the loads/ to see how a brand new browser/new client would load the images.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, when the new images are triggered, I get a screen painting, maybe it's slow internet.

Comment: Run the code in my example, it's 95% the same and it works fine

Comment: I think I found my problem, thanks a lot for your help again.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to append the `img` (?).

Everything else works fine.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  // Preload images
  var images = [
                'http://placehold.it/500x100?text=image0.png',
                'http://placehold.it/500x100?text=image1.png',
                'http://placehold.it/500x100?text=image2.png',
                'http://placehold.it/500x100?text=image3.png'
               ],
               i,
               img;
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = images[i];
    $("body").append(img);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```